# Most elegant way of keeping a list updated when editing/adding/deleting individual items in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

suppose I have two views in my AngularJS app.

One maintains a list of objects (displayed with an ng-repeat).

The user can click on one of those, and the app uses ui-router to open a sub-state with a view that displays that clicked object in an editeable form, including a "delete"button.

Now, once the user clicks "update", the object is sent to a REST api, but I would also like to reflect those changes in the list of items.

What is the correct AngularJS-way of updating the list of objects when the subview changes the individual object?

Comment: details provided are not specific enough to know how you have things set up. See [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to update the source list when your $http.post returns -- and angular will update views for you.

Comment: So what is the correct way of sharing that list with the subview?

Comment: "Correct" is such a loaded term. There are multiple ways you can accomplish this: if your sub-view is handled by a directive, you can set up your scope to bind from the parent. You could also use $emit, $broadcast and $on to broadcast events about data updates. It's really up to how you want to do it.